# How can I extract text between nth instance of forward slashes?

Tags: regex, re2

I want to extract all words between "products" and / (forward slash) or period (.)

In the example below, I want to extract "pants" and "shoes"

[www.site.com/products/pants.html](http://www.site.com/products/pants.html)

[www.site.com/products/shoes/sneakers.html](http://www.site.com/products/shoes/sneakers.html)

The closest I came was this `(?<=/products/).*($.|/)`
How do I include "." OR "/"

Comment: One more thing: please add a tag for the language you are using, as different languages support different regex features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *nth* occurance is e.g. two:

```
^(?:[^\/]*\/){2}([^.\/]+)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/i8ljNC/1)

- `^` start [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `(?:` [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) `)`
- `[^` [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `]`
- matches [captured](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to *group 1*

Comment: You don't need to escape forward slashes - they have no special regex meaning. That some languages *delimit* regex use forward slashes is not relevant to the regex solution.

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, I'm aware of that but no language-tag was added and slash is commonly used as a pattern-delimiter (escaped slashes in OP's regex let one conclude its use inside such). So I thought in case of doubt better too much as too little escaping. 